# ColdFusion Dropbox - Error in call to API function

Tags: coldfusion, dropbox-api

I am trying to used Dropbox API from ColdFusion and I am running some simple tests to understand how it works. I am trying to list all the folders from my Dropbox account and I am using this piece of code:

```
<cfset jsonCall = StructNew()>
<cfset jsonCall.path = "Shared">

<cfhttp url="https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder" method="post">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer LXldZbIAwawAAAAAAAAYUHqCbBQjBPfoWybyRrhivVViX7qq2x8oPK45QZ5WZkGr"/>
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(jsonCall)#">
</cfhttp>
```

Of course, the TOKEN is not real.

And I am getting the following error from Dropbox:

> Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": request body:
>   unknown field 'PATH'

Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: PATH is serielaized to upper case. Does Dropbox expect a certain case? try: `<cfset jsonCall["path"] = "Shared">`

Comment: Yes, you're right. It must be the upper case... Is there any way to make ColdFusion respect the case or force it to lowercase or something?

Comment: When using the square bracket notation coldfusion maintains case.

Comment: The CF function to make a string lower case is `lcase`.

Comment: Regarding how to preserve case, [Bernhard's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690947/coldfusion-dropbox-error-in-call-to-api-function#comment72505981_42690947) is probably the simplest. There are also server and application level settings, such as "Preserve case for Struct keys for Serialization" depending on your CF version. See [SerailizeJSON](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html).